# Failed to install gems via Bundler. remote: ! remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app. remote: remote: ! Push failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I tried all the solution on stack overflow but nothing worked for me.

Here is my problem

Heroku logs -t

```
 ID 3d636cae-b623-44f8-8aee-7eb12dfcccc0
    -----> Ruby app detected
    -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
    -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
           Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
           Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
           Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
           Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
           devise-4.6.1 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
           current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
           Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
           Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
           Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
           devise-4.6.1 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
           current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
     !
     !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
     !
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
     !     Push failed
```

Comment: it says you need ruby >= 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
devise-4.6.1 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
           current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
```

That is pretty clear. 
You should probably update your ruby environment on local machine to at least 2.1.0 and update your `gemfile` also.

or

https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/3.5.10

downgrade to `gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.10'` as it's the last devise using ruby under 2.0.

I would opt for the first option.

Comment: gem install bundler
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
 bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.

Comment: Yeap, that's why I would choose to do an upgrade to ruby to 2.5.1 at least, and update all the system. Also because the newer versions still should have legacy support.